# How to use a nested query to update a value in another table?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table (TablevVariables) which stores the last file updated date, the latest log date imported, etc, which is basically storing the values so that that the duplicate data import won't happen if the tool run multiple times a day.

So each day, the logs will be appended to a log archive table which will be used later for other historical data analysis. Then update the `TableVariables.Keyvalue=<latest date of the log file>`.

Update Template:

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_column='new value' WHERE something='some value';
```

My Update Query:

```
UPDATE TablevVariables SET [TablevVariables].KeyValue =
    (SELECT Max([xxxx_Archived_Log].[年月日]) FROM xxxx_Archived_Log)
WHERE [TablevVariables].KeyName="xxxx_Archived_Log";
```

When I try to execute this query, access throws the error that "Operation must use an updatable query".

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for guidance, I used a work around for this issue. Assigned the value to a variable and then passed it in a normal query.

```
txtSQLcmd = "SELECT Max([年月日]) FROM xxxx_Archived_Log;"
dtDateValue = DateValue(FetchAValueFromTable(txtSQLcmd))
txtSQLcmd = "UPDATE TablevVariables SET [TablevVariables].KeyValue = #" & dtDateValue & "# WHERE [TablevVariables].KeyName='xxxx_Archived_Log';"
ExecuteSQLcmd (txtSQLcmd)

Function FetchAValueFromTable(ByVal strSQL As String) As String
Dim cnn1 As ADODB.Connection
Set cnn1 = CurrentProject.Connection
Dim myRecordSet As New ADODB.Recordset
myRecordSet.ActiveConnection = cnn1
myRecordSet.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
myRecordSet.LockType = adLockOptimistic
myRecordSet.Open strSQL
FetchAValueFromTable = myRecordSet.Fields(0).Value
myRecordSet.Close
Set myRecordSet = Nothing
Set cnn1 = Nothing
End Function

Function ExecuteSQLcmd(ByVal strSQL As String)
   DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
End Function
```